# Regex in javascript check string

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the string contains html:

```js
const containsHTML = (str) => /<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(str);
console.log(containsHTML('<br>s')) // expect false
```

In my case i expect `false`, because `s` is not wrapped with HTML tag. How to fix the code?

Comment: Well your reg exp matches the br tag and says it is fine. Nothing stating the whole line needs to match.

Comment: obligatory link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Comment: HTML supports plain text nodes... Don't see why you consider `s` is not allowed after `<br>`?

Comment: @epascarello, so how to avoid situations if the string is not wrapped in html, could you help please? In the above situation i need to get false

Comment: Depends what it's for.  If you're looking to make sure the person didn't add html before doing something like `myContainer.innerHTML = stringFromUser` then most browsers will add missing end tags anyway, so just an opening tag is enough to "get html".

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: `/<([a-z]+.*)>.*<\/\1>/i`

```js
const containsHTML = (str) => /<([a-z]+.*)>.*<\/\1>/i.test(str)

console.log(containsHTML('<br>s'))    // expect false
console.log(containsHTML('<p>s</p>')) // expect true
```

Comment: if i set `console.log(containsHTML('<br/>')) // expect true`, but i get false. Why?

Comment: I fixed your expression, by reusing the open tag group in the expected closing tag.

Comment: @Asking because the regex above only checks for surrounding open-close tags.